# Unable to connect Arduino ClearCore device to MQTT server hosted on raspberry pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, mqtt, mosquitto

## **My Goal:**

I am trying to communicate with an MQTT server (I'm using mosquitto) hosted on a raspberry pi from a ClearCore device which I have programmed using Arduino.

## **My Issue:**

I have found numerous examples online which achieve what I want using similar devices and techniques. However I am unable to make a connection from my ClearCore device using my Arduino software to the MQTT broker hosted on my raspberry pi.

## **My Setup:**

I am using an Ethernet connection from my clear core device to my raspberry pi. I am using a **Teknic CLCR-4-13**. I am not using DHCP. I am setting the IP address of the raspberry pi each time it reboots so I always know what it is (see command below). I have created the mosquitto.conf file (port: 1883) and the password_file where I define a "username" and "password".

I run this command whenever I reboot my pi so I don't have to make a static IP.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.23 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

## **What I have tried:**

- From my PC - using an Ethernet connection and a python script I am able to connect, subscribe, and publish to my MQTT server using the IP address of the raspberry pi as the name of the MQTT server.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as pub

MQTT_SERVER = "192.168.1.23"
MQTT_PATH = "dev/test"
credentials = {'username':"user",'password':"pass"}
import time
while True:
    pub.single(MQTT_PATH, "Hello Pi!", hostname = MQTT_SERVER, auth = credentials)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(".")
```

- To verify I can transmit data from the ClearCore device and raspberry pi using an Ethernet cable I have successfully sent UDP packages using an Arduino program. I use the same mac and IP address.
- I have tried changing the MQTT version by defining it in the Arduino program to older versions.
- I have used Wireshark to monitor the Ethernet traffic when I run the program to verify a connection attempt is being made.

## **My Arduino Program:**

*Note: everything compiles and program runs successfully, but it is unable to connect to MQTT server*

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>

//#define MQTT_VERSION MQTT_VERSION_3_1
//#define MQTT_VERSION MQTT_VERSION_3_1_1
//#define MQTT_VERSION MQTT_VERSION_5_0

// Function prototypes
void subscribeReceive(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length);
 
// Set your MAC address and IP address here
byte mac[] = {0x24, 0x15, 0x10, 0xb0, 0x00, 0x3f};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 23);
 
const char* server = "192.168.1.23";
 
// Ethernet and MQTT related objects
EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(ethClient);

void setup() {
  // Useful for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Start the ethernet connection
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);              
  
  // Ethernet takes some time to boot!
  delay(3000);                          
 
  // Set the MQTT server to the server stated above ^
  mqttClient.setServer(server, 1883);   
 
  // Attempt to connect to the server with the ID "myClientID"
  if (mqttClient.connect("myClientID","user","pass")) 
  {
    Serial.println("Connection has been established, well done");
 
    // Establish the subscribe event
    mqttClient.setCallback(subscribeReceive);
  } 
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Looks like the server connection failed...");
  }
}

void loop() {
  mqttClient.loop();
 
  mqttClient.subscribe("dev/test");
 
  if(mqttClient.publish("dev/test", "Hello World"))
  {
    Serial.println("Publish message success");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Could not send message :(");
  } 
  // Dont overload the server!
  delay(4000);
}

void subscribeReceive(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  // Print the topic
  Serial.print("Topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
 
  // Print the message
  Serial.print("Message: ");
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
  {
    Serial.print(char(payload[i]));
  } 
  // Print a newline
  Serial.println("");
}
```

## **Command from Raspberry Pi**

```
mosquitto_sub -d -u user -P pass -t dev/test
```

I use this to see messages when they come in from the pi.

## **where it fails...**

```
mqttClient.setServer(server, 1883); 

if (mqttClient.connect("myClientID","user","pass"))
{
    //error message
}
```

## **Thoughts of potential issues:**

Most examples I have seen of similar projects - people are using "test.mosquitto.org" as their server name, but because I have configured my own MQTT server on my raspberry pi I instead use the IP address of the raspberry pi as the server name. This worked when I connected from my PC using a python script, but I don't know if this is an issue in my Arduino program.

I hope I provided enough information. Please let me know if I there is something else you might want to see that might help - I appreciate all feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are setting the IP address of your device to be the same as your raspberry pi server.

```
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 23);
 
const char* server = "192.168.1.23";
```

That's not going to work. Make the device IP something different, like `IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 24)`.

Comment: I get what you are saying but I have no idea what the IP address of the device is. I have yet to figure that out. I have tried setting the IP address of the ClearCore device through Arduino but with no success. I was hoping that because I connected to the MQTT server from my PC using only the IP address of the pi as the server name I would not need the IP address of the device looking to publish. If this is not the case I am currently trying to get in contact with Teknic to see if they can help.

Comment: Are you using an ethernet crossover cable to connect the ClearCore to the pi?

Comment: I am yes. I was actually able to solve my issue. You are right by the way - the IP address of the server needs to be different than the IP address of the ClearCore device. The people over at Teknic were able to help me set the IP address of the device. Once I did that I used the IP address of the device to set the ethernet connection and the IP address of the Raspberry Pi to connect to the server.